# Add to current function "Total" the logic with ignoring some values

Tags: javascript

My project is about to inserting hours, how much you have spent time.
It working great with integer values, but now i need to add string values.
Something like Sunday ="NotWorknig"; Monday = "8"; Tuesday = "ill";

```
function TotalP1() {
    var text1_p1 = 0;
    var text2_p1 = 0;
    var text3_p1 = 0;
    var TotalAmount = 0;

    text1_p1 = $("#text1_p1").val() == '' ? 0 : $("#text1_p1").val();
    text2_p1 = $("#text2_p1").val() == '' ? 0 : $("#text2_p1").val();
    text3_p1 = $("#text3_p1").val() == '' ? 0 : $("#text3_p1").val();



    TotalAmount =
        parseInt(text1_p1) +
        parseInt(text2_p1) +
        parseInt(text3_p1);


    $("#texttotal_p1").val(TotalAmount);

}
```

I want to rewrite function and make it to work same but with ignoring string values or specific integer values for example "29" will be "Holiday" and if user inserted Holiday value is 29 but it's ignored by function and doesn't affect sum. Without giving me "Nan" value. Any tips, tutorials guys )?

Comment: You can use `Number.isInteger(whatevervalue)` to check if something is an int or not

Comment: can i ignore with same way specific integer value ? if it's 7 i don't count/sum

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

```
function TotalP1() {
    var text1_p1 = 0;
    var text2_p1 = 0;
    var text3_p1 = 0;
    var TotalAmount = 0;

    text1_p1 = $("#text1_p1").val() == '' ? 0 : $("#text1_p1").val();
    text2_p1 = $("#text2_p1").val() == '' ? 0 : $("#text2_p1").val();
    text3_p1 = $("#text3_p1").val() == '' ? 0 : $("#text3_p1").val();

    var parsedValueP1 = parseInt(text1_p1);
    var parsedValueP2 = parseInt(text2_p1);
    var parsedValueP3 = parseInt(text3_p1);

    if(!isNaN(parsedValueP1)) {
      TotalAmount += parsedValueP1;
    }

    if(!isNaN(parsedValueP2)) {
      TotalAmount += parsedValueP2;
    }

    if(!isNaN(parsedValueP3)) {
      TotalAmount += parsedValueP3;
    }

    $("#texttotal_p1").val(TotalAmount);

}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
function TotalP1() {
  var text1_p1 = 0;
  var text2_p1 = 0;
  var text3_p1 = 0;
  var TotalAmount = 0;
  var numberRegex = /^\d+$/; //Only for Integers

  text1_p1 = $("#text1_p1").val() == '' ? 0 : $("#text1_p1").val();
  text2_p1 = $("#text2_p1").val() == '' ? 0 : $("#text2_p1").val();
  text3_p1 = $("#text3_p1").val() == '' ? 0 : $("#text3_p1").val();

  if(numberRegex.test(text1_p1)) {
     TotalAmount += parseInt(text1_p1);
  }

  if(numberRegex.test(text2_p1)) {
    TotalAmount += parseInt(text2_p1);
  }

  if(numberRegex.test(text3_p1)) {
    TotalAmount += parseInt(text3_p1);
  }

  $("#texttotal_p1").val(TotalAmount);

}
```

Comment: Thanks Taimoor, is it correct,if i want to ignore integer value  with = 1 ? if(text1_p1 =1) { TotalAmount = parseInt(text1_p1) } else { TotalAmount += parseInt(text1_p1)

Comment: You can modify the regular expression like this
var numberRegex = /^[023456789]+$/;

numberRegex.test("0456328") returns true
numberRegex.test("014") returns false

It matches each digit, if digit lies in the character set(0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) then valid otherwise invalid.

Answer (score 0):

First prepare an array of values that you want to ignore, like:

```
let arr_ignore = [7, 8, "holiday"];
```

Then just check if the inserted value is in the ignored values:

```
if(!arr_ignore.includes(some_value))
  your_function();
```

Comment: u mean like this ?if (!arr_ignore.includes(text1_p1)) {
        TotalAmount += parseInt(text1_p1);
    }

Comment: @whitefang yes.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/x9d3p04m/

You can add as many parameters you want

```
 function calculate(...numbers){
      var totalAmount = 0;
      numbers.forEach(function(element) {
        if(Number.isInteger(element)){
          totalAmount += element;
        }
        else {
          totalAmount += 0;
        }
      });
      return totalAmount;
    }
    var a = calculate(1,1,1,2,3);
    var b = calculate("I'm 0", "I'm 0", 10);
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
```

In your case

```
    text1_p1 = $("#text1_p1").val() == '' ? 0 : $("#text1_p1").val();
    text2_p1 = $("#text2_p1").val() == '' ? 0 : $("#text2_p1").val();
    text3_p1 = $("#text3_p1").val() == '' ? 0 : $("#text3_p1").val();

calculate(text1_p1 , text2_p1 , text3_p1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the sort of thing you are looking for in your updated question which includes strings, commmented to explain parts.

```
function TotalP1() {

    // Array of dates and days?? you don't want included in the sum
    var excludeArray = [29, 31, "sunday"]; 

    // Object for excluded dates/days responses
    var excludeResponses = {29: "29th is a holiday day", 31: "31st is a holiday day", "sunday": "Not working on Sundays"}; 

    // Values from inputs put into an array to loop through - makes it easier to scales as you can just add new inputs here
    var values = [
        $("#text1_p1").val(), 
        $("#text2_p1").val(), 
        $("#text3_p1").val()
    ];

    var totalAmount = 0;

    // Now loop through the values and add to the total amount of throw response/error
    $.each(values, function(key, value){

        //Test ifvalue is in the exclude array
        if($.inArray(value.toLowerCase(), excludeArray) < 0){

            //Test if value is only digits
            if(/^\d+$/.test(value)){
                // Value is only digits - parse and add to sum total
                value = parseInt(value);
                totalAmount += value
            }else{
                //Value is in exclude array but not only digits, deal with as you wish
            }

        }else{
            //Get exlcude response from object - change value to lower case for consistancy
            var response = excludeResponses[value.toLowerCase()];

            //check response was found in object
            if(response != "undefined" || error != null){
                //response found - give to user
                console.log(response);
            }else{
                //Responses not found in exclude responses for value debug this before production version
            }
        }
    });

    $("#result").val(totalAmount);
}
```